# Gitlab CI not invoking the 'pages' job

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a project hosted on Gitlab. The project website is inside the `pages` branch and is a `jekyll` based site.

My `.gitlab-ci.yml` looks like

```
pages:
  script:
  - gem install jekyll
  - jekyll build -d public/
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - public
  only:
    - pages

image: node:latest

cache:
  paths:
    - node_modules/

before_script:
  - npm install -g gulp-cli
  - npm install

test:
  script:
    - gulp test
```

When I pushed this configuration file to `master`, the pipeline executed only the `test` job and not `pages` job. I thought maybe pushing to `master` didn't invoke this job because `only` specifies `pages` branch. Then I tried pushing to `pages` branch but to no avail.

How can I trigger the `pages` job?

Comment: when should the pages job be executed? on every branch? befor, after or simultan with test?

Comment: afair without defined stages https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/README.html#stages - pages job only runs when test is completed successfully.

Comment: It should run whenever I push/merge to pages branch. And yes even after test was completed, it didn't run.

Answer (score 1):

You're right to assume that the `only` constraint makes the job run only on the `ref's` or `branches` specified in the `only` clause.

See https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/README.html#only-and-except

It could be that there's a conflict because the branch and the job have the same name. Could you try renaming the job to something different just to test?

Comment: The documentation says that `pages` is a "special" job. What does this mean? Would changing the name affect nothing?  https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/#pages

Comment: @ChiragArora you should keep the job name `pages` - that's what is going to deploy your site with GitLab Pages. If you change the job's name, your site will not be deployed.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try a couple of things.
First, I'd put in this `stages` snippet at the top of the YML:

```
stages:
  - test
  - pages
```

This explicitly tells the CI to run the `pages` stage after the `test` stage is successful.

If that doesn't work, then, I'd remove the `only` tag and see what happens.

Comment: What actually worked was that I had to push .gitlab-ci.yml to the pages branch itself and not to the master branch. The documentation is poorly documented and doesn't explicitly tell you to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Complementing @rex answer's:

You can do either:

```
pages:
  script:
  - gem install jekyll
  - jekyll build -d public/
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - public
```

Which will deploy your site regardless the branch name, or:

```
pages:
  script:
  - gem install jekyll
  - jekyll build -d public/
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - public
  only:
  - master # or whatever branch you want to deploy Pages from
```

Which will deploy Pages from `master`.

Pls let me know if this helps :)

Comment: What actually worked was that I had to push .gitlab-ci.yml to the pages branch itself and not to the master branch. The documentation is poorly documented and doesn't explicitly tell you to do this.

Comment: There's plenty of docs on GitLab Pages: https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/pages/. Well, when working with Git, it's expected that you checkout a new branch from your default branch (usually `master`). Therefore, each branch would contain the same files, except for the files being changed from that branch. (So, each branch would have a `.gitlab-ci.yml` file) => See https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging for reference. But you're right, I don't think there's a doc explicitly saying that. ;)

Comment: @MSBerends this is documented here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pages/getting_started_part_four.html#branching, if you want to take a look. Hope it helps :)

Comment: I did, I found it out, thanks! Now finding out how to beautify our R `pkgdown` website :)

Comment: @MSBerends cool! Glad you sorted it out! :) you can take a look at these example projects and see how gitlab-ci is configured to help you how to do it for your use case :) https://gitlab.com/pages